# Выборка данных из XML

Tags: java, xml, sax

Что-то совсем запутался..
Есть простейший XML файл вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <level>
    <name>
    <nick>
    ...
  </level>
  <level>
    <name>
    <nick>
    ...
  </level>
</root>
```

Требуется с помощью SAX парсера получить значение тэга "name" по образцу, переданному в парсер, найти секцию `<level>` содержащую это значение и считывать все элементы только этой секции для передачи в конструктор класса.
Значение тэга `<name>` в пределах **всего документа** - уникально.

```java
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

// Здесь мы определили анонимный класс, расширяющий класс DefaultHandler
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
  // Поле для указания, что тэг title начался
  boolean film = false;

  // Метод вызывается когда SAXParser "натыкается" на начало тэга
  @Override
  public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // Если тэг имеет имя title, то мы этот момент отмечаем - начался тэг title
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Жмурки")) {
      film = true;
    }
  }

  // Метод вызывается когда SAXParser считывает текст между тэгами
  @Override
  public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    // Если перед этим мы отметили, что имя тэга film - значит нам надо текст использовать.
    if (film) {
      sb.append(new String(ch, start, length));
      film = false;
    }
  }
};

// Стартуем разбор методом parse, которому передаем наследника от DefaultHandler, который будет вызываться в нужные моменты
saxParser.parse(input, handler);
```

Comment: Как пробовали? Что не получилось?

Comment: Не могу разобраться, как вытаскивать данные из секции. Разобрался, как получать названия секций, а дальше никак.

Comment: При парсинге текстового содержимого узла вызывается метод `ContentHandler.characters`

Comment: Это я знаю, документацию уже наизусть выучил, а вот реализовать не получается ((

Comment: Что такое "не получается"? Какие ошибки возникают? Где код, который "не получается"?

Comment: Пытаюсь приспособить вот этот код

Comment: Хороший код. И какая с ним проблема? Что, в итоге, оказывается в `sb`? (это же `StringBuilder`?). Кстати, можно писать прямо так `sb.append(ch, start, length);`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53406/discussion-between-anton-shchyrov-and-tariel).

Comment: @Anton Smirnov  Антон, прошу прощения, выбило в пятницу, если можно, я готов продолжить.

Comment: Переходите в чат и ответьте на вопрос